# CSS two divs next to each other (w/o line break)

Tags: html, css

I want to put 2 `<div>s` next to each other. How can I do this?
Both should be 50% width. Can someone help correct my code?

This is the code:

```
    <hr class="hr--small">
    <div class="grid">

    <div class="grid__item text-left">
      <p class="site-footer__links">{{ 'layout.footer.copyright' | t }} &copy; 
      {{ 'now' | date: "%Y" }} {{ shop.name | link_to: '/' }} • All Rights Reserved
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="grid__item text-right">
      <p class="site-footer__links">
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Privacy Policy</a> •                               
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Terms & Conditions</a>
      </p>
    </div>
```

At the moment they appear correctly left & right, but with line break. Just want them to appear on the same line.

Comment: Have you tried any CSS?

Comment: Try [`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display?v=example#Values).

Comment: I started typing `2 divs` and Google auto completed it to `2 divs next to each other`. How wonderful

Comment: As a side note, if you are a beginner I would advise not to be editing Shopify layouts as your first project. Get a professional to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what grid-framework you are using, but I'm sure that `text-left` and `text-right` are helper-classes that provide a text-align property.

A solution for your problem is to make the divs float, like I demonstrated in this Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hptv52gv/.

Comment: Thank you for that brief and easy to implement solution. How would you modify it so that the second div wraps under the first div on mobile? For example, if you used that on a desktop it looks great, but on mobile it cuts out the second div because there is a lack of screen space.

Answer (score 0):

You can float both div elements and clear the container, using inline-block and box-sizing to fit the true width of the container:

```
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

.grid__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;  
}
```

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jx6jebqe/)

Answer (score 0):

By default, divs are block elements. This means, among other things, that they drop to a new line each time. There are a few css techniques you can use to get divs to stay on the same line (`float: left`, `display: inline`, `display: flex`), but my favourite is `display: inline-block` The only issue with this is that there is a slight bug in that sometimes the whitespace (spaces or newlines) in your html file can cause your elements to wrap to a new line. You can get around this by removing the whitespace like so:

```
    <div class="grid__item text-left">
      <p class="site-footer__links">{{ 'layout.footer.copyright' | t }} &copy; 
      {{ 'now' | date: "%Y" }} {{ shop.name | link_to: '/' }} • All Rights Reserved
      </p>
    </div><div class="grid__item text-right">
      <p class="site-footer__links">
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Privacy Policy</a> •                               
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Terms & Conditions</a>
      </p>
    </div>
```

Then in your css, you'd have something like this:

```
.grid__item{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This solves my problem! :D
I just added <div id> to the code & css, so it doesn't affect the other grids on the page!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `table` element to control this layout. [See example](https://jsfiddle.net/nx8611rz/).

Comment: Are we in the 90's again?

Comment: Simple solution for a simple question. Why bombard a newbie

Comment: OK, I retracted my downvote, [but really](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design) this is the last suggestion you need to provide ([read the first rule](http://www.goodwebsiteinspector.com/en/html-rules-avoid-table-based-layouts-deep-div-nesting-deprecated-tags-bad-navigation-structure))

Comment: Google would be nauseous with your ancient HTML layout.

Comment: How unnecessarily aggressive